# How to open ui-bootstrap dropdown on clicking over angular highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angular-ui-bootstrap

This is the config object that I am passing to highchart directive and getting click event on clicking the highchart column, now on clicking the any column of highchart I want to open the dropdown there:

```
options: {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column'
                        },

                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Oct 2015', 'Nov 2015', 'Dec 2015', 'Jan 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'March 2016']
                    },
                    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                        title: {`enter code here`
                            text: 'Volume'
                        }
                    }, { // Secondary yAxis
                        title: {
                            text: 'Sentiment'
                        },
                        opposite: true
                    }],
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Volume - Same period last year',
                        type: 'column',
                        data: [1410, 610, 400, 785, 450, 400],
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function(e) {
                                    vm.showDropdown = true;
                                    vm.dropDownStyle.top = e.clientY;
                                    vm.dropDownStyle.left = e.clientX;
                                    console.log('event', e);
                                    $scope.$apply();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        color: '#2CAFC7'
                    },  {
                        name: 'Volume - Last 180 days ',
                        type: 'column',
                        data: [1210, 710, 700, 485, 410, 350],
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function(e) { // here I am getting click event
                                    console.log('clicked');
                                    vm.showDropdown = true;
                                    vm.dropDownStyle.top = e.clientY;
                                    vm.dropDownStyle.left = e.clientX;
                                    console.log('event', e);
                                    $scope.$apply();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        color: '#4C79BF'
                    }],

                    func: function (chart) {
                        //setup some logic for the chart
                        $timeout(function () {
                            chart.reflow();
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can either use the `is-open` attribute which takes in an expression, add a boolean variable to determine if the dropdown is open, set it to true on the column`s click callback...

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

> is-open $  (Default: false) - Defines whether or not the dropdown-menu is open. The uib-dropdown-toggle will toggle this attribute on click.

Comment: is-open is the only thing I am missing. I am doing with ng-show but ui-bootstrap not showing the dropdown because I am not changing is-open. Thanks again